# MySQL Update where Condition on Primary Key is slow

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-5.6

MySQL Version : 5.6.27

Table : load_report_data

Engine : InnoDB

Structure:
[image]

Explain Query :
[image]

Index :-
[image]

Inspite of id column being Primary key but running update where id = xxx is running is slow and also instead of Using Index, MySQL Explain says Using Where.I have enabled the MySQL Slow Query Log and it says this Update statement is running slow.

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong here and why this simple update query is running slow?

Comment: What is the datatype of `id`?

Comment: @NishantNair its Integer.

Comment: Are you running this query on a local machine or remote machine?

Comment: @Q.Holness I am running this query on Amazon RDS.

Comment: Check your optimizer statistics for your tables in data dictionary, if they updated far then do `analyze table`.useful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-statistics.html

Comment: @Ikrom I already did Analyze table and also did Optimize Table.But still same result

Comment: May be your index is not in memory or there are some other processes in the system. At the time of running the query can you check the cpu/memory/iostat of the machine. See if you can get any clue. I do not find any issue with the table structure and the query. May be due to less memory mysql is not loading any index and taking time.

Comment: @ManishVerma key_buffer_size  = 16777216 which I believe is 16 MB, that should be enough no??

Comment: How much is your row count ? If the size of your index is more than 16MB then it might be the issue. Calculate your index size roughly as number of bytes in an index * count. This you have to do for all the index you have in the database.

Comment: @ManishVerma Select count(*) as count from load_report_data; gives 35690, but that being said the number of rows will go on increasing every hour.Because we have some automation process running every hour.

Comment: Can you provide mail me the dump of your sample data so that I can investigate. Seems interesting problem to solve. :)

Comment: @ManishVerma your email id?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote from where clause id = **'99514'**

```
update load_report_data set status = 'Completed' ,updated_at = '2017-08-06 01:01:25'  where id = 99514
```

Comment: @NisantNair Same Result :(

Comment: what is the execution time ?

Comment: it takes almost 3 Seconds

Comment: have you checked with `explain`?

Comment: @NishantNair Please check the screenshot of Explain query in the question it says Using Where

Comment: are you updating the current datetime for updated_at? if yes then use `now()`